# Foreign key constraint failure when trying to insert because of key change

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Content object which refers to a set of Tag objects in a ManyToMany relationship.  As part of persisting a new Content object I look in PostgreSQL to see if the Tag already exists and if it does then I add the reference to it to the Content object and attempt to save the Content object.  The issue I am having is that when I do this I am associating Tags with ids e.g. 1, and 2 with the Content and when I attempt to save the content it fails with a foreign key violation because it says Tag with id 10 does not exist.  I stepped through the code and when I add the Tag to the set of tags associated with Content it has the correct id (i.e. 1 and 2) so why when I save it does it change to a different id?  I am using JPA, Hibernate, Spring, and PostgreSQL.  I've attached the hibernate Content object below.  The "content_tag" table just consists of content_id and tag_id which is foreign key references to the content and tag tables. To clarify: the tags in this instance are already created and I am only adding the association by searching for them in the database and adding their association to the content

Here is the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "content_tag" violates foreign key constraint "tag_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (tag_id)=(12) is not present in table "tag".
```

The code showing the attempt to save:

```
for (final String tag : request.getContent().getTags()) {
    final List<Tag> current = tagRepository.findByName(tag);
    if (current.isEmpty()) {
        final Tag newTag = new Tag(tag);
        tagRepository.save(newTag);
        content.addTag(newTag);
    } else {
        content.addTag(current.get(0));
    }

}
final Content response = contentRepository.save(content);
```

and here is the content class:

```
@Entity(name = "Content")
@Table(name = "content")
@TypeDef( name= "StringJsonObject", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)
public class Content implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "StringJsonObject")
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "content_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="content_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.add(tag);
        tag.getContents().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.remove(tag);
        tag.getContents().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Content)) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((Content) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }
}
```

Tag entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Tag")
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Content> contents = new HashSet<>();

    public Tag() {}

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Content> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setContents(Set<Content> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Tag tag = (Tag) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, tag.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all check if you are using a transaction. and it's also better to provide tag entity here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the configuration of your relation in content entity to this:

```
@JoinTable(name = "content_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "content_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This caused by transaction,U can't read uncommitted data, U may commit a transaction after U create a line of 'tag'.

Comment: The tags are already persisted in this case prior to this transaction. I am reading them from the database not creating new ones in this instance